# how to use XPath just return number

Tags: xpath

```
    <li><a href="javascript:noAction();" class="cur"  attrshowval="bank" attrval="FMZL,FMSQ,TWZL,HKPATENT,USPATENT,EPPATENT,JPPATENT,WOPATENT,GBPATENT,CHPATENT,DEPATENT,KRPATENT,FRPATENT,RUPATENT"><b>bank</b><span>(7)</span></a></li>
```

how can I use XPath just get number 7 without "()"

Now I use the below code while getting "(7)"

```
str(html.xpath('//a[contains(@attrshowval,"bank")]/b/span/text()'))
```

Comment: what version of xpath are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
str(html.xpath('substring-before(substring-after(//a[contains(@attrshowval,"bank")][1]/span,"("),")")'))
```

Or, another version replacing all brackets in the expression

```
str(html.xpath('translate(//a[contains(@attrshowval,"bank")][1]/span,"()","")'))
```

Output in both cases is

> 7

Answer (score 0):

And just for fun, here's another possible expression:

```
replace(replace(//a[contains(@attrshowval,"bank")]/span,"\(",''),'\)','')
```